# document.hidden is incorrectly false when used in a WebBrowser control

Tags: javascript, vb6, webbrowser-control, minimized, visibilitychange

I want to detect when a window is minimized in JavaScript, so I am using `document.hidden`. In the below snippet, click "Start" and minimize the window by clicking the minimize button, toggling the application icon in the taskbar, using <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>, using <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, etc.

When the window is minimized, you will see "hidden" appear in the textarea.

```js
var startButton = document.getElementById("start");
var stopButton = document.getElementById("stop");
var ta = document.getElementById("ta");

var id;
startButton.onclick = function() {
 id = setInterval(function() {
  ta.value += document.hidden ? "hidden\n" : "visible\n";
 }, 1000);
};

stopButton.onclick = function() {
 if (id) clearInterval(id);
};
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<br />
<textarea id="ta" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea>
```

No issues there.

However, I am hosting this JS code in VB6.

I have created a simple project with a form with a `WebBrowser` control and a `CommandButton`. My only code is this:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    WebBrowser1.Navigate "http://localhost:1234/mypage.html"
End Sub
```

Clicking the command button takes me to the same page:

[image]

In VB6, "hidden" is displayed for these three cases:

- clicking the minimize button
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>
- <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

But not, in this case:

- toggling the application icon in the taskbar

I've also noticed that `"hidden"` is only displayed the *first* time the window is minimized. If you minimize it again, it will display "visible".

I'm guessing this is a bug with how WebBrowser controls integrate with JS? Does anyone have any workarounds for this?

---

I may soon repurpose this question into a broader one, since this has less to do with `document.hidden` being wrong and more to do with `WebBrowser` not integrating nicely with JS's [Page Visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API).

A more general problem that I have discovered is that the `visibilitychange` handler does not fire when run in a page hosted by a `WebBrowser` control in VB6, but works totally fine in the browser:

```js
var ta = document.getElementById("ta");
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function ()
{
 ta.value += document.visibilityState + "\n";
});
```

```html
<textarea id="ta" cols="50" rows="20"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around it by listening to the `Resize` event, and whenever the `WindowState` changed, I'd set a property in my JS code indicating the state:

```
Private Sub Form_Resize()
    Static lWindowState As Long
    Dim lNewWindowState As Long
    Dim lOldWindowState As Long

    lNewWindowState = m_DesktopForm.WindowState
    lOldWindowState = lWindowState

    If lWindowState <> lNewWindowState Then  
        lWindowState = lNewWindowState

        Dim bHidden As Boolean
        bHidden = (lWindowState = vbMinimized)          
        Call CallByName(MyJSObj, "windowIsHidden", VbLet, bHidden)
    End If
End Sub
```

My JS has an object (that VB can reference) like this:

```
MyJSObj = {
    windowIsHidden: false
}
```

Then I added a method to wrap `document.hidden`:

```
function isDocumentHidden() {
    // if document.hidden is true, trust that. If it's not true, then fall back on what VB says
    return document.hidden || MyJSObj.windowIsHidden;
}
```

I use that method in my code instead of `document.hidden`.